# QtNetwork active interface change detection

Tags: qt, network-programming, qtnetwork

I am aware this question is *howto oriented*, but I am getting desperate. Lets say some computer has more than one hardware network interface, `eth0` and `wlan0`, the first one is onboard `Ethernet` port, the other one represents `PCI WiFi card`. What I would like to achieve is that the my `Qt` app while running, can detect if someone (for testing purposes, I myself) in operating system disconnects computer from `LAN`. Once app detects **link failure**, it tries to **connect to same `LAN`** via other available interface, `wlan0` or vice versa.
I am reading [Qt 5 Bearer management](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/bearer-management.html) docs, but I simply do not get needed info. Now, should I open `QNetworkSession` with `open()` and `connect` to `QNetworkSession::stateChanged(QNetworkSession::State state)` or are there any other ways to do it in `Qt` fashion?

Comment: What OS is that? We resolved it but Qt's own way is not a satisfactory.

Comment: Hooking up to QNetworkSession::stateChanged makes sense as you suggest. Why don't you try and proceed this way and see how it goes?

Comment: @AlexanderVX I am working on platform independent app (`Windows`, `Linux`, `Mac OS X`, `Android`, ...) and the mechanism must be therefore platform independent.

Comment: @ManuelH because I am little confused, minutes ago I've found [void QNetworkConfigurationManager::onlineStateChanged(bool isOnline)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkconfigurationmanager.html#onlineStateChanged). Will try both!